# Querying Android AudioEffect Equalizer for bands before attaching to audio session

Tags: android, audio

Is there a clean way to query Android audio fx for supported parameters (i.e. number of bands in equalizer, or if virtualizer supports strength) before creating audio fx object and attaching it to audio session? Currently to get that I just play something silently, query all fx and stop, but this seems clumsy to me. Any other ideas? I suspect I can get these with each class settings but I am not sure how to use them...

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30162069/3496570

Comment: How about number of eq bands and their ranges?

Comment: See another answer of mine http://stackoverflow.com/a/30477747/3496570

Comment: and also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16267328/3496570