# Bass Boost not working in android

Tags: android, bass, audioeffect

*when i run this code only simple sound is playing BassBoost is not working when change the seek bar,have i done anything wrong.
how i have watched some tutorials in Google,on stack-overflow  none of them were answered.

```html
 player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.song);
player.start();
 

    bb = new BassBoost(0, player.getAudioSessionId());
      bb.setEnabled(true);
      player.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);
      



 bassbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
          boolean fromUser) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         bb.setStrength((short) (progress * 10));
        }
       });
```

Comment: really ..no answer??

Answer (score 4):

> Check whether it is supported or not.

```
bassBoost = new BassBoost(0, 0);
bassBoost.setEnabled(true);

if (bassBoost.getStrengthSupported())
{
    short word1 = bassBoost.getRoundedStrength();
    bassBoost.setStrength(word1);
}
```

> And you can also check that whatever you're testing on supports it (it is device-dependent). You can use:

```
final Descriptor[] effects = AudioEffect.queryEffects();

// Determine available/supported effects 
for (final Descriptor effect : effects) {
    Log.d(TAG, effect.name.toString() + ", type: " + effect.type.toString());
}
```